# SO says I can set bounties, even though I do not have enough reputation

Tags: support, reputation, bounty, notifications

Today I edited a post to make it more clear and I got +2 reputation as usual. The only other thing is that it also said I can now set bounties on questions in my notifications. I looked in my profile, and it says that my next privilege is to set bounties at 75 reputation.  I also read the [article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) on setting bounties and I cannot do it on any question. The article also states that you require 75 reputation even though I only have 62. I just want to know if it is a bug showing me this notification or if it is a bug that is saying you require 75 reputation.

Here is a screenshot of the notification:

[image]

Comment: Could be bug, but it is also possible that you received upvotes which were later reverted. Those pushed you over the 75, but after being reverted the system treats your profile as they were never there, so you don't see -10 or a drop in your reputation histogram. You can also check [Why did I gain/lose reputation? Can I audit my reputation history?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269653)

Comment: If there is one universal truth about Stack Overflow, it is that caching makes people believe that Stack Overflow has a lot of bugs.